# AngularJs ng-show on specific element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to show a prog bar on element clicked.
this is my .jsp:

**list.jsp**

```
<div class="mb-pane" ng-style="{height: panelsHeight}">
<file-system-meeting refresh="global.refreshMeetings"></file-system-meeting>
```

**contentList.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

```
<!-- the "more" button and "actions buttons". This should be refactored 
<div class="pull-right"></div>-->

<!-- the core meeting display stuff. Really really simple. We should take care of the forced "size". -->
 <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
    <!-- ng-click='progressRun()' -->
        <a href="#meetings/{{meeting.id}}" ng-click="progressRun($event)" >
           <!--  <img ng-if="meeting.iconId" class="mb-repo-icon" ng-src="<c:url value="/restful/meetings/" />{{meeting.id}}/icons/{{meeting.iconId}}/thumbnail" />  -->
            <img ng-if="!meeting.iconId" class="mb-repo-icon" src="<c:url value="/img/thumbnail.png" />" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h3>{{ meeting.titolo }}</h3>
        <h4>Sub Title</h4>
        <h6>Creato Da: {{meeting.autore}}</h6>
        <div id="prog" class="progress" ng-show="runp">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                60%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-right">
        <h5>Part: {{meeting.num_partecipanti}}</h5>
        <h5>Doc: {{meeting.num_doc}}</h5>
        <h5>Durata: {{meeting.durata}} min</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can show progress bar on a clicked element?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/) see if you can use that perhaps or see how their code works at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to set a scope.

so in your controller you would have something like this:

```
$scope.functionName = function() {
   $scope.trueValue = true;
}
```

You then use ng-show on the element you want to show as something like this ng-show="trueValue"

You will also have to define scope.trueValue to be false out of this function.. Also if you want to toggle the true value you just have to do this in the function:

```
$scope.functionName = function() {
   $scope.trueValue = !$scope.trueValue;
}
```

Comment: This code it allow me to show prog bar, but on every list element, I need to show prog only on single clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your click element

```
<a href="#meetings/{{meeting.id}}" ng-click="progressRun($event)" >
               <!--  <img ng-if="meeting.iconId" class="mb-repo-icon" ng-src="<c:url value="/restful/meetings/" />{{meeting.id}}/icons/{{meeting.iconId}}/thumbnail" />  -->
                <img ng-if="!meeting.iconId" class="mb-repo-icon" src="<c:url value="/img/thumbnail.png" />" />
            </a>
```

// Controller JS

```
$scope.runp = false;

$scope.progressRun = function ($event) {
   $scope.runp = true;

}
```

Comment: I did this, but progressive bar shows on every list element, I need to show progressiv only on clicked element.

Comment: "but progressive bar shows on every list element"

Does not make sense, What do you mean by this sentence. May be you missed some important chunk of code to share with us.

Comment: Its simple...click on list item --> the progressbar is displayed on each element, but I want it to appear only on the item clicked. Nothin more.

Comment: It's simple to you because you can see it in your browser. We don't see. We try to give solution with our imagination and assumption.